# Not able to remove from Database using node js/mongodb/socket.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

This is the schema of my database table 'users'

```
{
   "_id": {
    "$oid": "572255b0dad7d9781f92d6bd"
   },
   "local": {
       "password": "$2a$08$JMHr7CMBNkFqi1xxFvO9je1w9qi2BP4tR9Z81FsA2N267PNIBD3ma",
       "email": "a@a.a"
   },
   "__v": 0
}
```

I am trying to remove this from my database using the following code:
functions.js:

```
function deleteUser(finishedEmail){
   try{
     var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
     console.log("success");
   } catch(e){
     console.log("fail");
   }
   if(socket !== undefined){
       var email = finishedEmail;
       socket.emit('userDelete',{
         email:email
       })
   }
}
```

server.js:

```
    var col2 = db.collection('users');
    socket.on('userDelete',function(data){
        var email = data.email;
        console.log(data.email);
        col2.deleteOne({email: email}, function(){
            console.log("successful deletion");
        });
    });
```

In my console I receive the logs: "a@a.a" and "successful deletion". But the email is not deleted. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried the following:

```
col2.deleteOne({local:{email: email}}, function(){
    console.log("successful deletion");
});

col2.deleteOne({email: email}, function(){
    console.log("successful deletion");
});

col2.deleteOne({local.email: email}, function(){
    console.log("successful deletion");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your server.js you have to write -

```
col2.deleteOne({"local.email": email}, function(){
   console.log("successful deletion");
});
```

Comment: unfortunately I tried that and it said "Unexpected Token ." , so after the local. So that doesn't work